# R : Extract elements of same index & depth level of a list

Tags: r, list

Here is a list :

```
# Build a toy list
x1=letters[1:3]
x2=letters[4:5]
x3=letters[1:8]
toy_list=list(list(list("ABX",x1),
                   list("ZHK",x2)),
              list(list("CCC",x3)))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ABX"

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "ZHK"

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "d" "e"



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "CCC"

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

Let's suppose I want to extract all elements, for example, in 2nd position, at a "deep level" of 3. In other way I want to extract elements of index `[[1]][[1]][[2]]`, `[[1]][[2]][[2]]`, `[[2]][[1]][[2]]`. Which means I want my output to be

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

How would you do that in a generalize way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With purrr, you can use `at_depth(2, ...)` where 2 indicates the depth level, and `...` is an extractor (name/integer) or function. Simplifying the structure afterwards,

```
library(purrr)

toy_list %>% at_depth(2, 2) %>% flatten()

## [[1]]
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "d" "e"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to when it comes to install libraries again and again, but your solution is so beautiful ...

Comment: You could hack it with `lapply`, e.g. `lapply(toy_list, function(x){lapply(x, function(y){y[[2]]})})`, but that won't fully flatten.

Comment: Updating this per warning: "! `at_depth()` was deprecated in purrr 0.3.0 and is now defunct. ℹ Please use `map_depth()` instead." As advised, `toy_list %>% map_depth(2,2) %>% flatten()` works.